# Do I get the credit for the damage and kills my sabotaged enemies do?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

The Quarian Infiltrator in Mass Effect 3 Multiplayer has the very nice Sabotage power which can cause certain enemies to fight on your side for a while. The ability is very useful, but I'm wondering how the damage those "converted" enemies do to other enemies is handled.

- Does the damage from sabotaged enemies count for the XP you get?
- How is it handled for medals that you get for a certain number of kills/assists?

Comment: I don't recall ever having this happen but I'll test this tonight

Answer (score 3):

This answer is from experience as a Quarian Infiltrator. You definately get experience for the damage these enemies do as far as what it counts towards more then likely it will be an assist of course unless they kill something then you will actually get a kill from them.  Im gonna take a good guess and say their kills count towards biotics as they function somewhat like a turret or drone when it comes to kills and assists. when a kill pops up it will even say (for example geth trooper) your name then Geth Trooper then the name of the kill

Answer (score 1):

You get XP from sabotaged enemy kills.

Medals going for kills. And when target dies from sabotage weapon drawback it is a tech kill.